# how to rest dynamic text box value when rest button click

Tags: javascript, php

I want rest the value in the text box when the rest button click in dynamical created table .how do i do it?

```
$table .='<tbody><tr>';
           $table .='<td>' . $row["emp_id"] . '</td>';
           $table .='<td>' . $row["emp_name"] . '</td>';
           $table .='<td>' . $row["date"] . '</td>';

           $table .='<td><input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" value="'.$row["ot_hour"] .'" size="4"></td>';
           $table .='<td><button type="button" name="ot_approval_rset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ot_approval_rset" " id="'.$row["emp_id"].'">Reset</button></td>';
           $currentMonth= date('Y-m');
           $query01 ="SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `ot_hour` ) ) ) AS timeSum 
           FROM otresquest
           WHERE emp_id ='".$row["emp_id"]."' AND date LIKE '$currentMonth%' AND overtime_status=6";
           $statement = $connect->prepare($query01);

           if($statement->execute())
           {  

            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            foreach($result as $row){
               $table .='<td>' . $row["timeSum"] . '</td>';
               }   
            }

           $table .='</tr></tbody>';
```

java script code

```
$(document).on('click', '.ot_approval_rset', function() {
    emp_id = $(this).attr('id');
    //i need write code here to reset (00:00:00) value of ot_approval_rset input box
  });
```

[image]
when click the reset button particular row ot hours should 00:00:00 .

Comment: Use `.parents()` to go up to the `tr` element, from there `.find()` the text input element, then set `.val('')`. No need to bother fetching any element IDs at all.

Comment: not every time need to reset .some time admin may need to ot request value

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about now. You asked how to reset that field on click of the button, I told you how you could go about that. (Although the last part should be rather `.val('00:00:00')`, of course.) No clue how or where your admin comes into play now, or what you even mean by that last comment.

Comment: can i give me sample answer?

Comment: you have to use form in each row to reset all value at once using form.reset()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try this code

```
 $(document).on('click', '.ot_approval_rset', function() {
        var otherInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val('00:00:00');
      });
```

It may be help to you

Comment: bro it have problem .when press the rest button all the td input value be rested